# How to add loader in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, loader, preloader

How to add Loading effect in VUE js plus Laravel. 
This is a single page website in vuejs, i want to add loader when i change the route.

Means when i click to another router, it takes time to fetch data and show meanwhile i want to show loader. Or When i submit a form i takes time for submit meanwhile i want to add loader.

Means when i click to another router, it takes time to fetch data and show meanwhile i want to show loader. Or When i submit a form i takes time for submit meanwhile i want to add loader. 
Means when i click to another router, it takes time to fetch data and show meanwhile i want to show loader. Or When i submit a form i takes time for submit meanwhile i want to add loader. 
Means when i click to another router, it takes time to fetch data and show meanwhile i want to show loader. Or When i submit a form i takes time for submit meanwhile i want to add loader.

Help please in VUE js + Laravel

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code in your **`app.js`** file

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   // add loader
   next()
})
router.afterEach(() => {
  // terminate you loader
})
```

so Full file is

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueProgressBar from 'vue-progressbar'

window.Fire =  new Vue();

Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
    color: 'rgb(143, 255, 199)', //normal color for progress bar
    failedColor: 'red', //color for failed progress bar
    height: '2px'//height of progress bar can be changed here
})


Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.Fire =  new Vue();


let routes = [

    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'posts',
        component: post,
    },
    {
        path: '/general',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
    },
   

];

let router = new VueRouter({

    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // add loader
 VueProgressBar .start();
 next()
})
router.afterEach(() => {
 // terminate you loader
  VueProgressBar.finish();
})

const app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    router,
    data: {},
    methods: {}
});

window.Fire = new Vue();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are requesting while browsing through the pages, the loader can work accordingly.

```
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        loaderIsActive: false,
        items: null,
    }),

    mounted() {
        this.fetch();
    },

    methods: {
        async fetch() {
            this.loaderIsActive = true;
            this.items = await axios.post('YOUR API');
            this.loaderIsActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you can use it.